# Converting a Tuple of numpy arrays to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I have a tuple of numpy arrays:

[image]

I have been trying to convert it into a 2D (7x1800) numpy array for a while now and can't seem to find the correct code to convert it.

Please help me if there is a command I can use to do this.

Tried to convert it to list from tuple and then numpy array but to no avail.

Comment: Please add the code with a small example to your question. It's not clear what kind of input you have from the screenshot, because for a regular tuple `t = (np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6]))` works simply `np.array(t)`

Comment: @MariaKozlova Please post this as an answer. I think this is exactly what OP needs

Comment: @MariaKozlova I second the suggestion to post an answer considering `np.array(t)` is more efficient (i.e. faster) than `np.vstack(t)`, as suggested by Andrej.

Comment: What are you trying?  SInce the arrays are all the same size, `np.array` should work without problems.  `np.vstack` and `np.stack` should also work.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy-vstack). Consider this example:

```py
tpl = np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6]), np.array([7, 8, 9])

print(tpl)
```

Prints:

```
(array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9]))
```

Then:

```
print(np.vstack(tpl))
```

Prints:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Repeating what I said in the comment, simply applying `np.array` to tuple will do the job

```
t = (np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6]))
np.array(t)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

I don't have time right now to test the efficiency myself, so quoting [jared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12131013/jared) from the comments, will return to this later

> `np.array(t)` is more efficient (i.e. faster) than `np.vstack(t)`

Comment: I've added an answer that performs the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I ran some performance tests on the three main options: `np.vstack`, `np.array`, and `np.stack`. As you can see below, the difference isn't significant, but `np.array` is consistently faster than the rest, though the margin decreases as the number of arrays increases.

[image]

Code to reproduce the analysis:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def method1(data):
    return np.vstack(data)

def method2(data):
    return np.array(data)

def method3(data):
    return np.stack(data)

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
M = 1800
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda N: [rng.random(M) for _ in range(N)],
    kernels=[
        method1,
        method2,
        method3
    ],
    labels=["vstack", "array", "stack"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2,15)],
    xlabel="len(data)",
)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Comment: `stack/vstack` both use `concatenate`

Comment: Right. The main point is to show that stacking rather than `np.array` is slightly slower.

Comment: Error messages are also different when the arrays don't match in shape.